# What is the correct grammar for this passive construction?

Tags: passive

Attempting to translate, "I should have been told about it," I said:

> **Ich** hätte darüber erzählt worden sein sollen

but was corrected by a native German speaker with:

> **Mir** hätte darüber erzählt worden sein sollen

Can someone explain to me the reason for the correction?

Comment: In thee words: nominative vs. dative …

Comment: The correction is not quite correct,btw. -- the "hätte" already covers the (unreal) past, so the additional past tense in "worden" is superfluous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most idiomatic translation for "I should have been told about it" is IMO "Man hätte mir das sagen sollen." Don't forget the option with "man" instead of a passive; "man" has a broader use than English "one".

But anyway, if you want a passive wiht the verb "erzählen", it works as follows. First type, standard case:

- Active: jemand-(NOM) erzählte mir-(DAT) das-(ACC)
- *werden*-Passive = convert ACC to NOM: "Das wurde mir erzählt"
  (If you want the direct object to be the addressee, use the verb "mich informieren" instead).

But now you actually have chosen a variant without ACC, so you get an impersonal passive without a new NOM:

- jemand-NOM erzählte mir-DAT davon
  --> "Mir wurde davon erzählt"

Note that there is also a *dative passive* with the auxiliary "bekommen", if you want to convert a dative to subject:

- Dat-Passive = convert DAT to NOM: "Jemand erzählte mir-DAT das-ACC" --> "Ich-NOM bekam das-ACC erzählt"

... and now you can fill in all those other auxiliary verbs... "jemand hätte mir das erzählen sollen" --> ...

Comment: Excellent! Just what I needed. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think most idiomatic is *Das hätte man mir sagen sollen.* with the thing in question being the topic.

Comment: Can you remove the misleading *direct object* term, which as we always state  doesn't exist in German?

Comment: Why do you "always state" that "it doesn't exist"? The term direct object is regularly used in German grammar. The Duden grammar uses it, specifically, as a cover term for accusative objects and sentential objects (since the latter don't show case) (2009, p. 814).